# VB: 3 error messages in Private Sub

Tags: vb.net

The following Sub shows these error-messages:

bold 1: "to many arguments to 'Friend WithEvents btnChoice As Button'"

bold 2: "to many arguments to 'Friend WithEvents imgPicture As Button'"

bold 3: "'Friend WithEvents btnChoice As Button' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed"

bold 4-8: "'Friend WithEvents imgPicture As PictureBox' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed"

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim intNextNumber As Integer

    For intNextNumber = 1 To 8
        btnChoice(**intNextNumber**)
        imgPicture(**intNextNumber**)
    Next

    Call MoveControls(btnChoice)
    Call MoveControls(imgPicture)

    For intNextNumber = 1 To 8
        **btnChoice**(intNextNumber).Visible = True
    Next

    Randomize()

    Dim aintRandomNumber(0 To 8) As Integer

    Call GetRandomNumbers(aintRandomNumber)

    For intNextNumber = 1 To 8
        Select Case aintRandomNumber(intNextNumber)
            Case 1, 2
                **imgPicture**(intNextNumber).Picture = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Jonas Bakari Reitan\Desktop\Bilde1.jpg")
                **imgPicture**(intNextNumber).Tag = "Sirkel"
            Case 3, 4
                **imgPicture**(intNextNumber).Picture = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Jonas Bakari Reitan\Desktop\Bilde2.jpg")
                **imgPicture**(intNextNumber).Tag = "Firkant"
            Case 5, 6
                **imgPicture**(intNextNumber).Picture = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Jonas Bakari Reitan\Desktop\Bilde3.jpg")
                **imgPicture**(intNextNumber).Tag = "Diamant"
            Case 7, 8
                **imgPicture**(intNextNumber).Picture = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\Jonas Bakari Reitan\Desktop\Bilde4.jpg")
                **imgPicture**(intNextNumber).Tag = "Pil"
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what behavior is desired compared to the existing code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve can give some tips about how to structure your question so that you get the best help.

Comment: It appears that you are referencing controls as if they are an array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your controls are named `imgPicture1` to `imgPicture8` you can access them by their name using the `Controls.Find` method.

```
Dim img = Me.Controls.Find("imgPicture" & index, True)
```